# Would MongoDB be a good fit for my industry?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, relational-database, nosql

I work in the promotional products industry. We sell pretty much anything that you can print, embroider, engrave, or any other method to customize. Popular products are pens, mugs, shirts, caps, etc. Because we have such a large variety of products, storing information about these products including all the possible product options, decoration options, and all associated extra charges gets extremely complicated. So much so, that although many have tried, no one has been able to provide industry product data in such a way that you could algorithmically turn the data into an eCommerce store without some degree of data massaging. It seems near impossible to store this information to properly in a relational database. **I am curious if MongoDB, or any other NoSQL option, would allow me to model the information in such a way that makes it easier to store and manipulate our product information better than an RDBMS like MySQL.** The company I work for is over 100 years old and has been using DB2 on an AS400 for many years. I'll need some good reasons to convince them to go with a non relational DB solution.

---

A common example product used in our industry is the Bic Clic Stic Pen which has over 20 color options each for barrel and trim colors. Even more colors to choose for silkscreen decoration. Then you can choose additional options for what type of ink to use. There are multiple options for packaging. After all that is selected, you have additional option for rush processing. All of these options may or may not have additional charges that can be based on how many pens you order or how many colors in your decoration. Pricing is usually based on quantity, so ordering 250 pens would be cost more per pen than ordering 1000. Similarly, the extra charge for getting special ink would be cheaper per pen ordered when you order 1000 than 250.

Comment: If you don't know why you need a non-relational DB and think it's "near-impossible" to store the DB in a relational DB, then you need a Celko book, not Mongo DB. Non-relational DBs have their uses, but avoiding learning how to use a relational DB isn't one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without wanting to sound harsh, this has the ring of a silver bullet question.

You have an inherently complex business domain. It's not clear to me that a different way of storing your data will have any impact on that complexity - storing documents rather than relational data probably doesn't make it easier to price your pen at $0.02 less if the customer orders more than 250.

I'd recommend focussing on the business domain, and not worrying too much about the storage mechanism. I'm a big fan of Domain Driven Design - this sounds like a perfect case for that approach.

Answer (score 1):

Using a document database won't solve your problem completely, but it probably can help.

If your documents represent the options available on a product and an order for that product, in most cases you will be accessing the document as a whole - it's nothing you can't do with SQL, but a good fit for a document database. Since the structure of the documents is flexible, it is relatively easy to define an object within the document as a complex type to define a particular option or rule without changing the database.

However, that only helps with the data - your real problem is on the UI side. The two documents together map directly to the order form, but whatever method you use to define the options/rules some of the products are going to end up with extremely complex settings pages.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, MongoDB is what you need. It doesn't have a strict documents structure, so you'll be able to create set of models you need and embed them into your product page in any order and combinations you need. Actually its possible to work with this data without describing the real model fields directly, so I (for example) can use fields my Rails application doesn't know about at all.

Also MongoDB is extremely easy to set up for replication and sharding. Also it supports GridFS virtual filesystem, so you can store images for your products with documents which describe them and manipulate them as a single object easily.

You should definitely give it a try.

UPD: Anyway it would be good to keep your RDBMS for financial data and crunching numbers, like grouping reports for the sales analysys and so on. NoSQL bases aren't very good at this.